# MS.Access - VBA Print Report From Form with 2 filter criteria in the DoCmd.OpenReport [where condition]

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm trying to print a batch ID data sheet from a form without opening the report.
Using the below code I can open the report showing just the data I want

```
Private Sub PrntbLblV1_Click()   
Dim str As String
str = "[BatchID] = " & Me.BatchID
DoCmd.OpenReport "RprtLblPrint", acViewPreview, , str
DoEvents
End Sub
```

This opens the record I want in print preview... however I want to just send the record to printer.. I've tried

```
 DoCmd.OpenReport "RprtLblPrint", acNormal, , str
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdPrint
   DoEvents
```

But it prints every batch transaction not just the current one... I think the problem is I have a further filter in the report property that filters on load to remove completed transactions [Complete] = False which is a true/false tick box..
I can't seem to nest the completed & batch criteria into the where part of the DoCmd.OpenReport
It keeps throwing a type mismatch error

```
str = "[BatchID] = " & Me.BatchID And [Complete] = False
```

and I've tried separating it

```
Dim str As String
Dim Cmplt As String
str = "[BatchID] = " & Me.BatchID
Cmplt = [Complete] = False
    DoCmd.OpenReport "RprtLblPrint", acNormal, , str And Cmplt
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdPrint
```

Any suggestion on how I can get the 2 filter criteria into the DoCmd.OpenReport where condition??

Comment: Try `str = "[BatchID] = " & Me.BatchID & " And [Complete] = False"`

Comment: Booooooom! worked first time... Thanks Kostas...

Comment: @KostasK., could write up an answer.

Comment: @KostasK. should write his comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It needs to be part of the filter string as in:

```
str = "[BatchID] = " & Me.BatchID & " And [Complete] = False"
```